# Update SelectList in MVC view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been working on my first .net MVC site.

I have a Viewmodel containing header and detail items. As part of my header the user needs to select a company/database to work from, based on this I do an ajax call back to the server to retrieve the relevant list data for the rest of the header.

Now in my details the user needs to be able to add and remove line as they please and the client wants inline editing.The lines also contain dropdowns that will be populated from my ajax request, but instead of doing a call to the server for every line to get the list data I would like to do this once the database has been selected and the just update the select list and send it with every line.

**Header Viewmodel**

```
public long PrId { get; set; }
    public string PrNumber { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public int SupplierID { get; set; }
    public string Justification { get; set; }
    public string ExpenseCompany { get; set; }
    public string RequestedBy { get; set; }
    public bool BookOrder { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpectedDeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryAdress { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public decimal DiscountValue { get; set; }
    public decimal DicountPercentage { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalExcl { get; set; }
    public decimal Vat { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalIncl { get; set; }
    public string CurrentUser { get; set; }
    public string PrevUser { get; set; }
    public string EvoPoNum { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> Companies { get; set; }

    public List<IFormFile> SupportingDocs { get; set; }
    public List<IFormFile> DeliveryDocs { get; set; }
    public List<PRLinesVM> Lines { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> Priorties { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> RequestbyUsers { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ExpenseCopanies { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Suppliers { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> DeliveryAddresses { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TaxTypes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PRProjects { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PRDepartments { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PRCosts { get; set; }
```

**Detail Viewmodel**

```
public int LineId { get; set; }
    public string PRCost { get; set; }
    public string PRDepartment { get; set; }        
    public string PRProject { get; set; }        
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceExcl { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceIncl { get; set; }
    public decimal DiscountPerc { get; set; }
    public int TaxType { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TaxTypes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PRProjects { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PRDepartments { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PRCosts { get; set; }

    public long PrId { get; set; }
```

**Main View**

```
@model PRHeaderVM
    <form asp-action="SubmitPR" role="form" id="WorkgflowForm" style="width: 100%;top:0;right:0;left: 10px; bottom:10px">


        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div style="padding-bottom: 40px;">
                            <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Company</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <select id="DbDropdown" asp-for="CompanyID" asp-items="@Model.Companies" class="form-control">
                                    <option>Please select</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
                            <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Supplier</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <select id="SuppDropdown" asp-for="SupplierID" asp-items="@Model.Suppliers" class="form-control">
                                    <option>Please select</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Jutification</label>
                        <br />
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <textarea id="Jutification" asp-for="Justification" class="form-control" rows="4">
                            </textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div style="padding-bottom: 40px;">
                            <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Expense Company</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <select id="expComp" asp-for="ExpenseCompany" asp-items="@Model.ExpenseCopanies" class="form-control">
                                    <option>Please select</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
                            <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Requested By</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <select id="Reqby" asp-for="RequestedBy" asp-items="@Model.RequestbyUsers" class="form-control">
                                    <option>Please select</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
                            <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">
                                Book order
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="Bookord" asp-for="BookOrder" class="from-control" style="width:100%;height:30px" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
                            <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">
                                Price Incl
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="priceincl" class="from-control" style="width:100%;height:30px" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div style="padding-bottom: 40px;">
                            <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Expected Delivery Date</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
                                    <input id="datetimepickercustom" type="text" asp-for="ExpectedDeliveryDate" class="form-control" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
                            <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Delivery Address</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <select id="DelivDropdown" asp-for="DeliveryAdress" asp-items="@Model.DeliveryAddresses" class="form-control">
                                    <option>Please select</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Priority</label>
                        <br />
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <select id="PrioDropdown" asp-for="Priority" asp-items="@Model.Priorties" class="form-control">
                                <option>Please select</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a id="btnaddval" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addVal('');">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>  Add Line
                    </a>
                </div>
                <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" style="height : 450px">
                    <thead style="width: 100%;display: table-column;table-layout: fixed;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:25px"></td>
                            <td>
                                PR Cost
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                PR Department
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                PR Project
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Description
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Quantity
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Price(Excl)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Discount %
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Tax Type
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Price(Incl)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                .......
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tbLines" style="height : 400px;position:fixed; overflow-y: scroll;width: 92%;">
                        @if (Model.PRCosts != null && Model.PRDepartments != null && Model.PRProjects != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var item in Model.Lines)
                            {
                                item.PRCosts = Model.PRCosts;
                                item.PRDepartments = Model.PRDepartments;
                                item.PRProjects = Model.PRProjects;
                                Html.RenderPartial("_PRDetails", item);

                            }
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

**Ajax call**

```js
function getFieldList() {
                            var url = "List";
                            var opt = document.createElement("option");
                            $.ajax({
                                data: $("#DbDropdown").serialize(),
                                type: 'GET',
                                cache: false,
                                dataType: 'json',
                                url: url,
                                success: function (result) {                                 
                                    $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                                        console.log(item);
                                        //How do i assign values to the SelectList in my model and not the HTML element
                                    });
                                },
                                error: function (ex) {
                                    alert(ex);
                                }
                            });
```

**Partial view for details**

```
@model PRLinesVM
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("lines"))

        <tr>
            <td>
                <Label name='Lines.LineId' style="width:15px">@Model.LineId</Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PRCost, new SelectList(Model.PRCosts, "Value", "Text"), "-Select Cost-", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PRDepartment, new SelectList(Model.PRDepartments, "Value", "Text"), "-Select Department-", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PRProject, new SelectList(Model.PRProjects, "Value", "Text"), "-Select Project-", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Quantity, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", @min = "0" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PriceExcl, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", @min = "0" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DiscountPerc, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", @min = "0" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TaxType, new SelectList(Model.TaxTypes, "Value", "Text"), "-Select Tax Type-", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PriceIncl, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", @min = "0" })
            </td>
            <td>
                <a id="btnAddVal" onclick='removeRow(@Model.LineId);' class="btn btn-danger">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>  Remove
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Where is your ajax code?

Comment: @Valkyriee Would you suggest i wrap the rest of the header and detail in a partial view to return the entire model with all the list data once the company has been selected?

Comment: Solution posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this myself by only rendering the rest of the page after the company has been selected.

With regards to the grid lines i used a partial view to add lines and fill the dropdowns for every line.